# How to get android widget sizes programmatically if they were expressed as percentages

Tags: android, layout

Is it possible to retrieve the dimensions of a widget if they were expressed as percentages of their parents' dimensions in the xml file? Take for example, I have an image view set in a linear layout. The image view's height is set to 0dp, then its weight is set to 0.5. Is it possible to programmatically get the actual height at runtime in dp? If yes, how is it done. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You call getHeight *after* the view has been laid out.  At that time the actual data should be in there.

Comment: @Moses, if you call the getHeight()  immediately after layout has been initialized it would return zero, try to call this method though some event like button clicklistner() or use handlers to give break when you actually try to read the Views height and width